# AngularJS Directive Transclude parent scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-transclude

I'm working on a directive and I'm using **transclude** so the **inner element** of the directive use is used inside it.

Let's say that this is my **directive's view**:

```
<div>
  <div ng-repeat="opt in options">
    <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Directive**:

```
app.directive("myDirective", function(){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: 'my-directive.html',
        scope: {
          options: '='
        }
    };
  });
```

And a simple use of it:

```
<my-directive options="someOptions">
     <p>{{someObject[$parent.opt]}}</p>
</my-directive>
```

This works just fine. My problem with this solution is that that `$parent.opt` is not very readable and clear...
Is there any other option?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your directive seems to be a very specific one.
How about passing the parent to the directive too?

```
<my-directive options="someOptions" object="someObject"></my-directive>
```

---

In the directive:

```
<div>
  <div ng-repeat="opt in options">
    <p>{{object[opt]}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

And then add `object: '<'` in your isolated scope declaration.

Comment: This solution because there is an `ng-repeat` inside your directive which always needs a parent object/array anyway.

Comment: It's indeed. The reason behind that "structure" is to try to isolate the different parts. I can't really use the object and bind it. Not for what I want to achieve. Thank you!